# How to exclude a range of virtual addresses that can be returned by malloc() in C?

Tags: pointers, memory-management, malloc, virtual-memory, virtual-address-space

Upon success, malloc() returns a pointer to a newly allocated memory. The pointer is a virtual address. By default, there is no control on what virtual address the malloc() returns. Is there a way to exclude a range of virtual addresses so that malloc() does not return addresses from this range to the pointer?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to create a unique range of virtual address space that corresponds to remote memory, that is allocated through my custom remote memory allocator.
However, even if my custom mmap() returns the desired range of virtual addresses, I need to make sure that these virtual addresses would not be used *first* by the regular malloc(). This can happen if the application decides to allocate local memory first, then try to allocate remote memory. Does this makes the use case a bit clearer? @RuudHelderman

Comment: What is "remote memory"? Two computers sharing memory? Is one computer going to dictate the address range to the other? Why not let each computer offset the shared addresses based on whatever `mmap` itself found to be free on the local side?

Comment: Remote memory is considered memory over pcie which can be mapped to applications virtual address space through ioremap(). However these details are irrelevant to my original question.

Comment: `ioremap` gives you the freedom to use any virtual memory region that happens to be available. So first let `mmap` allocate a memory region that has not been allocated yet (by leaving its first argument NULL), then call `ioremap` (feeding it `mmap`'s return value). `malloc` and `mmap` do not conflict, as long as you let _them_ choose the addresses.

Comment: Your approach gave me an idea. Suppose that the application calls mmap() when it starts, providing a fixed virtual address as the first argument, which is the virtual range that must be excluded from the normal malloc() "allocator". Is this virtual address range added to the application virtual address space? (even if it is not physically mapped at this point). If the answer is yes, then this address range is "excluded" from the malloc(). @RuudHelderman

Comment: You still haven't explained _why_ you need a fixed virtual address range. The whole point of virtual memory is to abstract away the fixed _physical_ memory addresses demanded by your hardware (i.e. the PCIe device). Please be aware [main is not the first function being executed](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html). Your memory region may overlap the data segment, allocated by `sbrk` before `main` was called. You might mitigate that risk by picking a (very) high address range, but it doesn't feel very portable. What works on one OS might segfault on another.

Comment: I need a fixed, virtual address region to statically allocate regions of this virtual address space across homogeneous machines. Each portion of the virtual address region is assigned to resources of each machine. This address space must be a contiguous window within the virtual address space of an app.